# Laravel-4 Pagination in Query Builder with form inputs

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Got a question if anyone can help out.

I have a query that has a collection of parameters and displays some results.

```
DB::table()
  ->join()
  ->where()
  ->orderby()
  ->select()
  ->get();
```

But the wheres are generated by a form input in the view. Basically this is a bunch of filters to get a table of results. I want to paginate that. if I change the get() to paginate(), and call $result->links() in the template, it does indeeed paginate and generates a bunch of results for me, however the problem is that when you move away from page 1, the links are just a _GET parameter and all the filter input does not get applied.

Is there a way I can have the pagination AND filters going at the same time? What is the laravel way of handling that? Or would I have to build some way of handling filters and pages? Any tips on that?

Cheers!

*** Solution ***
The solution was to make the form use GET method and persist the old filters to the Pagination using ->appends() method. Below is the modified code to do that if anyone else is looking.

```
$results = $query->paginate($this->report->inputs->per_page);
$query = array_except( Input::query(), Paginator::getPageName() );
$results->appends($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here's how I do it:

```
$orderBy = Input::get('orderBy', 'created_at');
$order   = Input::get('order', 'DESC');
$limit   = Input::get('limit', 100);
$name    = Input::get('name', '');

$result = DB::table()
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $order)
    ->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is what I am doing already. The issue here is slightly different.

I have a form on which parameters I am filtering on. Which is fine 

Form data:
tolerance:0.1
per_page:50
... many other filters...
filter:Filter

Then after the filter gets applied and results are filtered, I got to the second page and only thing that gets sent is this in query string parameters and no form data is submitted:
    page:2

So is there a way I can still keep the filters AND pagination?

Comment: So, when you go to the second page, the filters go away? It sounds like you need to persist the filter value on the page somehow. Is it an XmlHttpRequest or a standard HTTP request?

Comment: Ok I was being pretty stupid really... What I was doing was I had a form using POST and ->links() generates GET for the pages. Now I am looking into a way I can add the additional get params to the end of the list of links generated by ->links().

Comment: Right so the solution is to make the form use GET method and then use $paginator->appends() method.

In my case, it will be 
$results = $query->paginate($this->report->inputs->per_page);
$query = array_except( Input::query(), Paginator::getPageName() );
$results->appends($query);

The top line is the normal pagination call, and the following 2 lines, will add in existing input ignoring the page passed in previously.

Thanks for the help in making me realise how stupid I was in the first place :)

All fixed now.